# How to send an arbitrary string to a file?

Tags: cmd, windows-xp

How in CMD may one send an arbitrary string (e.g. from an environment variable) to a file?

Not e.g.

```
   echo %myarbitrarystring% > file.txt
```

since this is pranged by characters such as &.

And

```
   echo "%myarbitrarystring%" > file.txt
```

need not apply, since this sends the quotes too.

The similar questions I've seen on SO do not address this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "myvar=^^&&!!%%%%xyz--__++==(())**||\\??//~~>><<,,++"
SET my
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%myvar%") DO >a_filename.txt ECHO(myvar=%%a
GOTO :EOF
```

Should cover most characters

---

Amended to send data to a file

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't send anything to a file.

Comment: @chrisjj It works fine.  Try it again - there was an issue with `spaces/tabs` which has been corrected, but lines starting with `;` will fail.

Comment: "lines starting with ; will fail" Then close but no cigar :) Thanks anyway for the suggestion. BTW, I think line 5's myvar= is in error.